# "Let alone" sentence pattern

Tags: phrases, sentence-patterns

I have what I believe to be a simple question, regarding how "let alone" fits into a sentence.

Tell me if there is a difference in terms of correctness between these sample sentences:

1) "I refuse to play any video game, let alone a sports title, on easy."

or

2) "I refuse to play any video game on easy, let alone a sports title."

I sent the first one as a text to my friend, but after reading it, began to wonder if I got it right. This isn't life or death, but it certainly is bugging me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Let alone," as I think you know, is a way of emphasizing a thing that's really not going to happen.  Regarding the question of which sentence is correct, the first one works better because you have the emphatic phrase next to the thing it's emphasizing -- video game.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. Yeah, I didn't use it in the traditional sense, but this saves me from wondering about it in future situations. I scoured the internet for an answer but couldn't find anything. You've been a great help! Thanks.

Comment: There's quite a lot to the construction, and it's laid out in a famous publication that uses _let alone_ as an example of what constructions are like and how they work: [Fillmore, Kay, and O'Connor 1988, "Regularity and Idiomaticity in Grammatical Constructions: The Case of _Let Alone_"](http://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/~filip/fillmore+88.pdf)